# Prepared Statements in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, database-performance

Is this a prepared statement?

```
select
this_.col_id as col1_1_0_,
this_.col_label as col2_1_0_,
this_.col_definitionAsJSON as col4_1_0_ 
from
tbl_Rule this_ 
where
this_.class='org.rules.Table' 
and this_.col_label=?
```

If you remove the first "where" condition, then it is definitely a prepared statement and will be cached by the database. But what is about the first "where" condition? Does it prevent caching of this query by the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate always uses PreparedStatement for calls to the database.