# Prepared Statements Count in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, database-performance

On analyzing hibernate statistics for a Grails application there is an issue I can't understand. The value for PrepareStatementCount is increasing on each request. It doesn't matter if the request is the same or different. 
As I understood, each prepared statement is cached by the database in the query cache. So that on second request the database doesn't need to parse the sql statement again. It saves CPU usage on the database server.

I would expect, that if I send a request twice, the PrepareStatementCount should increase by 1. Do I have an issue with query cache or do I misinterpret the hibernate statistics?

An example of a query is posted in  [an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360610/prepared-statements-in-grails)